# Filtering a view in SharePoint list based on a year

Tags: sharepoint, filtering, spview

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

I want to create new view for my list. The list contains a column called `Year`, which is a number and contains, as name suggests, year. Eg.:

```
2012
2011
2010
2009
```

I would like create a view, where I would display only last 3 years. Under creating new view, I go to `Filter`, choose `Show items only when the following is true:`, pick column `Year` and... this is where I get lost.

How to write a condition, that a number should be greater that current year minus 3? I tried

```
[Year]-3
```

but this obviously couldn't be so simple. Please help me write this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Today]` returns the current date so you can use the following formula:

```
[Year] > YEAR([Today])-3
```